Question about SLOAD and JUMP/JUMPI in EVM Bytecode
I have a question about the behavior of EVM bytecode. When an SLOAD instruction is executed and the next opcode is a JUMP or JUMPI, can the value pushed onto the stack by the SLOAD be considered a valid jump destination?
Personally, I think it cannot and that it’s a false/unreachable path created by the solc compiler. Can anyone confirm or explain this behavior?
Thanks in advance!

Yes it can, this is how it could work in EVM bytecode



pc
opcode




0x00
PUSH1 0x0a


0x02
PUSH0


0x03
SSTORE <- store "0x0a" at "0x00"


0x04
PUSH0


0x05
SLOAD <- read "0x0a" at "0x00"


0x06
JUMP <- this will jump to the "0x0a" PC


0x07
PUSH0


0x08
PUSH0


0x09
REVERT


0x0a
JUMPDEST


0x0b
STOP



Experiment with it! https://www.evm.codes/playground?fork=cancun&unit=Wei&codeType=Mnemonic&code='w1%200x0avSSTOREvSLOADyzvREVERTyDEST~STOP'~%5Cnvw0y~JUMPwPUSHvz~%01vwyz~_
